# Getting wrong answer when calculating geometric series

Tags: r, tidyverse, accumulate

I am trying to use tidyverse accumulate function to calculate two geometric series.

[image]

This geometric series should give a result of 1871.445

I tried using the following line of code that gave me the answer 1200

```
sum(accumulate(seq(from=0, to=4, by=1/12), .init = 400, ~ .x/(1 + 0.5)))
```

I am also trying to calculate this geometric series:

[image]

This should give a result of 4.678613, but my line of code is giving me 3

```
sum(accumulate(seq(from=0, to=4, by=1/12), .init = 1, ~ .x*(1/(1 + 0.5))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accumulate` is used when result of previous iteration is used in next term of any sequence.  **Moreover, beauty of R lies in its vectorized operations.**  So you can do it directly.  I am also adding `accumulate` way of doing it, but you may notice that *argument `.x` is never used and therefore it is equivalent to taking a longer route when a shortcut is available in plain sight.*

```r
# 1st series
400/(1.5^((0:4)/12))
#> [1] 400.0000 386.7103 373.8621 361.4408 349.4322

#accumualate style (though redundant)
purrr::accumulate(0:4, .init = 0, ~400/(1.5 ^(.y/12)))[-1]
#> [1] 400.0000 386.7103 373.8621 361.4408 349.4322

# its sum
sum(400/(1.5^((0:4)/12)))
#> [1] 1871.445

#2nd series
(1/(1 + 0.5))^((0:4)/12)
#> [1] 1.0000000 0.9667757 0.9346553 0.9036020 0.8735805

#accumulate style
purrr::accumulate(0:4, .init = 0, ~(1/(1 + 0.5))^(.y/12))[-1]
#> [1] 1.0000000 0.9667757 0.9346553 0.9036020 0.8735805

#sum
sum((1/(1 + 0.5))^((0:4)/12))
#> [1] 4.678613
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need `accumulate` here, and its use doesn’t add anything worthwhile; the accumulation you are performing is just the *sum* — so use (only) `sum`:

```
t = seq(0, 5 - 1)
sum(400 / (1.5 ^ (t / 12)))
```

You *could* use `accumulate` (or rather, its sibling `reduce`!) *instead of* `sum`, but the resulting code would be more complex, for no added gain. But even if you used `reduce` your transcription of the equation is wrong.